# how to set variable fom key pair string

Tags: bash

In bash if there is a variable for example:

```
$var1="myvar=once upon a time"
```

From this value, how can I set a new variable called `myvar` to have value "once upon a time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare`:

```
$ declare "$var1"
$ echo "$myvar"
once upon a time
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
var1="myvar=once upon a time"
myvar="${var1#*=}"
echo "$myvar"
```

Output:

```
once upon a time
```

---

See: [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)